Do encoding schemes for variational algorithms apply to annealing methods (e.g. DWave)?
I understand there are some efficient encoding schemes for variational algorithms, that attempt to approximate the variational state using fewer qubits.  I'm thinking of 2 papers in particular, which are very closely related:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.01774:  SEction 3 "Minimal Encoding"
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.08507:  Section V " SYSTEMATIC ENCODING OF BINARY
VARIABLES"
The main idea is to approximate the parameterized quantum state using fewer qubits. To me, this seems like it's only possible given a circuit-based quantum computing model (e.g. IBM's quantum computers).  Does the idea still apply to annealers such as those provided by Fujitsu and DWave?

Are there other efficient, generic encoding schemes that apply to annealing-based methods?
